# Why do we use mid = low + (high – low)/2; but not mid = (low/2) +(high /2)?

Tags: binary-search

In binary search, we use `mid = low + (high – low)/2` instead of `(low + high)/2` to avoid overflow, however, can't calculate  `low/2` and `high/2` separately and then sum them up rather than `low+(( high-low)/2)`?

P.S. If `low + (high – low)/2` is more efficient, then why is it so?

Comment: Note that the equality `(low + high) / 2 = low / 2 + high / 2` does not always hold.

Comment: Yes, it is true that equality may not always hold in general but shouldn't it always be true for the integer indices? Thank You for helping me out 

Comment: No. Take two odd values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say both low and high are 3; then middle = 3/2 + 3/2 = 1+1 = 2, which actually is quite bad. :-)

The reason we don't use middle=high/2+low/2 is that it gives us the wrong result

Answer (score 1):

> Can't we calculate `low/2` and `high/2` separately and then sum them up rather than using `low+((high-low)/2)`?

Sure.

> If `low+(high-low)/2` is more efficient, then why is it so?

For a lot of hardware dividing is slower than adding and subtracting, so dividing twice might be slower than the method that uses more adding and subtracting.

Comment: Division by two *can* be very efficient with bit shifting, but that assumes the programming language and architecture actually support integer (as opposed to the generic number data type) & bit shifting, those aren't always guaranteed, and either requires a smart enough compiler or complicates the source code.